# Csv file load through logstash to elasticsearch not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am trying to load a `csv` file from Linux system through`logstash(docker based)` with the below `conf` file.

```
./logstash/pipeline/logstash_csv_report.conf

input {
  file {
    path => "/home/user/elk/logstash/report-file.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["start_time", "date", "requester", "full-name", "id", "config", "status"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
     hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
     index => "project-info"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

I do not know the reason that why is my `csv` file not getting uploaded into `Elasticsearch`. My `logstash` docker `logs` last few lines as follows. In my `logstash` i don't see any errors.

```
    logstash         | [2021-01-18T04:12:36,076][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.1}
    logstash         | [2021-01-18T04:12:36,213][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
    logstash         | [2021-01-18T04:12:36,280][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][497c9eb0da97efa19ad20783321e7bf30eb302262f92ac565b074e3ad91ea72d] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
    logstash         | [2021-01-18T04:12:36,282][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:".monitoring-logstash", :main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
    logstash         | [2021-01-18T04:12:36,474][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

My `docker-compose` file as follows.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'      
    volumes:
      - './elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    networks:
      - elk

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.1
    container_name: kibana
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    volumes:
      - './kibana:/usr/share/kibana/data'
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.1
    container_name: logstash
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - 'HEAP_SIZE:1g'
      - 'LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g'
      - 'ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch'
      - 'ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200'
    command: sh -c "logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash_csv_report.conf"
    ports:
      - '5044:5044'
      - '5000:5000/tcp'
      - '5000:5000/udp'
      - '9600:9600'
    volumes:
      - './logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline'
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch  
    networks:
      - elk
networks:
 elk:
  driver: bridge
```

In my `./logstash/pipeline` folder i have only `logstash_csv_report.conf` file.

Same `csv` file able to upload using `Kibana GUI` using `import` option.

Someone please help me to resolve this problem using `logstash` upload.

**Curl output.**

```
# curl -XGET http://51.52.53.54:9600/_node/stats/?pretty
{
  "host" : "3c08f83dfc9b",
  "version" : "7.10.1",
  "http_address" : "0.0.0.0:9600",
  "id" : "5f301139-33bf-4e4d-99a0-7b4d7b464675",
  "name" : "3c08f83dfc9b",
  "ephemeral_id" : "95a0101e-e54d-4f72-aa7a-dd18ccb2814e",
  "status" : "green",
  "snapshot" : false,
  "pipeline" : {
    "workers" : 64,
    "batch_size" : 125,
    "batch_delay" : 50
  },
  "jvm" : {
    "threads" : {
      "count" : 157,
      "peak_count" : 158
    },
    "mem" : {
      "heap_used_percent" : 16,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 4151836672,
      "heap_max_in_bytes" : 4151836672,
      "heap_used_in_bytes" : 689455928,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 190752760,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 218345472,
      "pools" : {
        "survivor" : {
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 143130624,
          "max_in_bytes" : 143130624,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 143130624,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 65310304,
          "used_in_bytes" : 39570400
        },
        "old" : {
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 2863333376,
          "max_in_bytes" : 2863333376,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 2863333376,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 115589344,
          "used_in_bytes" : 115589344
        },
        "young" : {
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 1145372672,
          "max_in_bytes" : 1145372672,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 1145372672,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 1145372672,
          "used_in_bytes" : 534296184
        }
      }
    },
    "gc" : {
      "collectors" : {
        "old" : {
          "collection_count" : 3,
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 1492
        },
        "young" : {
          "collection_count" : 7,
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 303
        }
      }
    },
    "uptime_in_millis" : 4896504
  },
  "process" : {
    "open_file_descriptors" : 91,
    "peak_open_file_descriptors" : 92,
    "max_file_descriptors" : 1048576,
    "mem" : {
      "total_virtual_in_bytes" : 21971415040
    },
    "cpu" : {
      "total_in_millis" : 478180,
      "percent" : 0,
      "load_average" : {
        "1m" : 1.35,
        "5m" : 0.7,
        "15m" : 0.53
      }
    }
  },
  "events" : {
    "in" : 0,
    "filtered" : 0,
    "out" : 0,
    "duration_in_millis" : 0,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0
  },
  "pipelines" : {
    "main" : {
      "events" : {
        "out" : 0,
        "duration_in_millis" : 0,
        "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0,
        "filtered" : 0,
        "in" : 0
      },
      "plugins" : {
        "inputs" : [ {
          "id" : "497c9eb0da97efa19ad20783321e7bf30eb302262f92ac565b074e3ad91ea72d",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "name" : "file"
        } ],
        "codecs" : [ {
          "id" : "rubydebug_a060ea28-52ce-4186-a474-272841e0429e",
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 2
          },
          "name" : "rubydebug"
        }, {
          "id" : "plain_d2037602-bfe9-4eaf-8cc8-0a84665fa186",
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "name" : "plain"
        }, {
          "id" : "plain_1c01f964-82e5-45a1-b9f9-a400bc2ac486",
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "name" : "plain"
        } ],
        "filters" : [ {
          "id" : "3eee98d7d4b500333a2c45a729786d4d2aefb7cee7ae79b066a50a1630312b25",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 39,
            "in" : 0
          },
          "name" : "csv"
        } ],
        "outputs" : [ {
          "id" : "8959d62efd3616a9763067781ec2ff67a7d8150d6773a48fc54f71478a9ef7ab",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0,
            "in" : 0
          },
          "name" : "elasticsearch"
        }, {
          "id" : "b457147a2293c2dee97b6ee9a5205de24159b520e86eb89be71fde7ba394a0d2",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 22,
            "in" : 0
          },
          "name" : "stdout"
        } ]
      },
      "reloads" : {
        "last_success_timestamp" : null,
        "last_error" : null,
        "successes" : 0,
        "failures" : 0,
        "last_failure_timestamp" : null
      },
      "queue" : {
        "type" : "memory",
        "events_count" : 0,
        "queue_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "max_queue_size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "hash" : "3479b7408213a7b52f36d8ad3dbd5a3174768a004119776e0244ed1971814f72",
      "ephemeral_id" : "ffc4d5d6-6f90-4c24-8b2a-e932d027a5f2"
    },
    ".monitoring-logstash" : {
      "events" : null,
      "plugins" : {
        "inputs" : [ ],
        "codecs" : [ ],
        "filters" : [ ],
        "outputs" : [ ]
      },
      "reloads" : {
        "last_success_timestamp" : null,
        "last_error" : null,
        "successes" : 0,
        "failures" : 0,
        "last_failure_timestamp" : null
      },
      "queue" : null
    }
  },
  "reloads" : {
    "successes" : 0,
    "failures" : 0
  },
  "os" : {
    "cgroup" : {
      "cpuacct" : {
        "usage_nanos" : 478146261497,
        "control_group" : "/"
      },
      "cpu" : {
        "cfs_quota_micros" : -1,
        "stat" : {
          "number_of_times_throttled" : 0,
          "time_throttled_nanos" : 0,
          "number_of_elapsed_periods" : 0
        },
        "control_group" : "/",
        "cfs_period_micros" : 100000
      }
    }
  },
  "queue" : {
    "events_count" : 0
  }
```

Comment: Can you share what you get when running `curl -XGET host.docker.internal:9600/_node/stats/?pretty` ?

Comment: @Val requested output added in the question section.

Comment: Are you sure that `/home/user/elk/logstash/report-file.csv` can be read by Logstash? I don't see that file being mapped to a volume accessible to Logstash

Comment: Oh yes, earlier it was out side of mounted volume, now have moved the `csv` to mounted volume `./logstash/pipeline` and restarted the containers and checked. still not able to see the data in `Kibana`.

Comment: Ok, but did you change the `path` in your `file` input accordingly?

Comment: Yes, updated the `csv` file path in my `logstash_csv_report.conf`file.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest configuration you now have?

Comment: In my `logstash_csv_report.conf` added `beats {
   port => 5044
 }

tcp {
   port => 5000
 }` it works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Val. The major problem was earlier my `csv` file was not in the logstash mounted volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `/home/user/elk/logstash/report-file.csv` can be read by Logstash. I don't see that file being mapped to a volume accessible to Logstash.

In your docker compose configuration you need to add another volume like this:

```
logstash:
  ...
  volumes:
    - './logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline'
    - '/home/user/elk/logstash:/home/user/elk/logstash'
```